# SkiaSharp library version 2.88.7 on .NET 7: issue where SKBitmap.Encode/Decode does not work for large images. SKCodec.Create returns null

Tags: out-of-memory, large-file-upload

```
SKData originalImageData = SKData.Create(inputStream);
SKBitmap decodedOriginalBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(originalImageData); //throw exception
SKCodec codec = SKCodec.Create(originalImageData); //always null
```

For smaller images, such as those smaller than the buffer size, this approach works. How can we modify it to handle larger images?